# Subnet Address with FLSM Method?

Tags: networking, subnet

I'm web programmer and i'm not familiar with networking , i have this next question i have searched many articles on the internet but it was not helpful and i found difficulties with understanding subnetting .. i preach it anyone who can help me to solve this question :)

The question is :

> You have been allocated a class B network address: 165.10.0.0/16
>
> ```
> Departments   Number of employees
> D1                   800
> D2                   200
> D3                    50
> D4                   1600
> D5                   210
> D6                    60
> D7                    60
> D8                    36
> D9                    210
> ```
>
> How to distribute this addresses over the departments with FLSM Method ?

Comment: where did you get this block from? This is a public block - and since you say - you are not aware of networking, I am just curious, whether you indeed want to expose this public block to the  Internet.

Comment: its uni small project i have and its important to me

Comment: O ok. So this is just a project where you are not going to configure it on a 'real router'. Then the simplest is - you can fit all of them into different /20 networks Because highest is - 1600 that should easily fit in 12 bits - so create multiple /20 networks for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
•   Max host in D4 which is 1600 and will take it to calculate subnet 
•   Address Size :  2^11-2=2046
•   Subnet Mask : 255.255.248.0
•   To calculate new subnet mask: 256 - 248 = 8
•   8 between networks and each one has 2046 addresses.




  Dep   Number of Employees Address Size    Subnet Address
        Subnet Mask Start - End IP  Broadcast Address
    D4  1600    2046    165.10.0.0/21   255.255.248.0   165.10.0.1 - 165.10.0.254   165.10.0.255
    D1  800 2046    165.10.8.0/21
        255.255.248.0   165.10.8.1 - 165.10.8.254   165.10.8.255
    D5  210 2046    165.10.16.0/21
        255.255.248.0   165.10.16.1 - 165.10.16.254 165.10.16.255
    D9  210 2046    165.10.24.0/21
        255.255.248.0   165.10.24.1 - 165.10.24.254 165.10.24.255
    D2  200 2046    165.10.32.0/21
        255.255.248.0   165.10.32.1 - 165.10.32.254 165.10.32.255
    D6  60  2046    165.10.40.0/21
        255.255.248.0   165.10.40.1 - 165.10.40.254 165.10.40.255
    D7  60  2046    165.10.48.0/21
        255.255.248.0   165.10.48.1 - 165.10.48.254 165.10.48.255
    D3  50  2046    165.10.56.0/21
        255.255.248.0   165.10.56.1 - 165.10.56.254 165.10.56.255
    D8  36  2046    165.10.64.0/21
        255.255.248.0   165.10.64.1 - 165.10.64.254 165.10.64.255
```

sorry for unstyled formatted text i couldn't paste my table here ..

Answer (score 0):

Host bits will be 11... Means each n/w will have 2^11 hosts
N/w bits will be 21... Means there will be (16-11) ie 5.. ie 2^5 n/w ie 32 n/w
SM = 255.255.248.0